How to dynamically add elements to a webpage using JavaScript?
I’m building a simple "to-do list" app using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I want to allow users to add new tasks by typing into an input box and clicking a button. When the button is clicked, the task should appear as a new list item on the page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>To-Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="taskInput" placeholder="Enter a task">
      <button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
      <ul id="taskList"></ul>

      <script>
        function addTask() {
          const taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
          const taskList = document.getElementById('taskList');

          // I'm not sure how to create a new list item dynamically
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>

What is the best way to create a new <li> element dynamically and append it to the <ul>? Should I use inner HTML or create Element, and why?

This question is similar to: Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
